# Drop elements from array if regexp does not match

Tags: ruby, arrays, regex

Is there a way to do this?

I have an array:

```
["file_1.jar", "file_2.jar","file_3.pom"]
```

And I want to keep only "file_3.pom", what I want to do is something like this:

```
array.drop_while{|f| /.pom/.match(f)}
```

But This way I keep everything in array but "file_3.pom" is there a way to do something like "not_match"?

I found these:

```
f !~ /.pom/ # => leaves all elements in array
```

OR

```
f !~ /*.pom/ # => leaves all elements in array
```

But none of those returns what I expect.

Comment: Are you aware that the `.` in `/.pom/` matches any character?

Comment: BTW, where does your array come from?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

How about `select`?

```
selected = array.select { |f| /.pom/.match(f) }
p selected
# => ["file_3.pom"]
```

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 5):

In your case you can use the [`Enumerable#grep`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/Enumerable.html#method-i-grep) method to get an array of the elements that matches a pattern:

```
["file_1.jar", "file_2.jar", "file_3.pom"].grep(/\.pom\z/)
# => ["file_3.pom"]
```

As you can see I've also slightly modified your regular expression to actually match only strings that ends with `.pom`:

- `\.` matches a literal dot, without the `\` it matches any character
- `\z` anchor the pattern to the end of the string, without it the pattern would match `.pom` everywhere in the string.

Since you are searching for a literal string you can also avoid regular expression altogether, for example using the methods [`String#end_with?`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/String.html#method-i-end_with-3F) and [`Array#select`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/Array.html#method-i-select):

```
["file_1.jar", "file_2.jar", "file_3.pom"].select { |s| s.end_with?('.pom') }
# => ["file_3.pom"]
```

Answer (score 3):

If you whant to keep only Strings witch responds on regexp so you can use Ruby method *keep_if*.
But this methods "destroy" main Array.

```
a = ["file_1.jar", "file_2.jar","file_3.pom"]
a.keep_if{|file_name| /.pom/.match(file_name)}
p a
# => ["file_3.pom"]
```